# FFMPEG Script Produces video of 1 second

Tags: python, bash, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to work the script found [here](https://github.com/dlnetworks/ffviz)

```sh
#########################
## START CONFIGURATION ##
#########################

# path to video playlist.txt
playlist="playlist.txt";

# output frame size
outsize="1920x1080";

# frames per second
fps="60";

# video bitrate
bv="20M";

# audio bitrate
ba="256k";

# video codec
cv="h264";

# audio codec
ca="libfdk_aac";

# output container format
fmt="flv";

# base frequency (Hz)
bfreq="20";

# end frequency (Hz)
efreq="1420";

#######################
## END CONFIGURATION ##
#######################

randfile="$(cat "$playlist" | rl | head -1)";
duration="$(mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration/String3%" $randfile)";
viz="volume=2,showcqt=s=1920x144:text=0:r=$fps:axis=0:basefreq=$bfreq:endfreq=$efreq:count=15:sono_g=4:bar_g=4:bar_v=35:sono_h=144:sono_v=bar_v*a_weighting(f):tc=0.1,rotate=1200*sin(200*PI/200*t):ow=24:oh=24:c=none,scale=$outsize,setsar=1/1[viz];[1:v]scale=$outsize,setsar=1/1[vid1];[viz][vid1]blend=all_mode=heat:shortest=1:repeatlast=0,hue="H="2*PI*t/420""";
enc="-s $outsize -c:a $ca -b:a $ba -c:v $cv -preset ultrafast -b:v $bv -profile:v high -level 4.2 -g "$(bc <<< $fps*2)" -bf 2 -x264opts keyint="$(bc <<< $fps*2)":min-keyint="$(bc <<< $fps*2)":8x8dct=1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r $fps";
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$1" -r $fps -i "$randfile" -filter_complex $viz $enc -t $duration -shortest -f $fmt "$2";
```

When running however I am only getting a video output of 1 second, there is no exit message the process just ends.

The command I am running is `./ffviz.sh http://50.7.77.114:8277 output.mp4`

The 1 second clip does contain the correct mp4 and and audio, so I believe the process is working, I am not able however to make it run it for longer than 1 second.

Comment: what value ultimately is present in the duration variable? (edit the script to output the command it will run before it runs it?)

Comment: Ah I see that is output as `00:00:01.600`

Comment: Very strange, this script should be taking a continuous shoutcast radio stream and outputting it on a video, it makes no sense for for the length to be that short :/

Comment: What duration would you like it to have? If the input is a continuous stream then it will have an undefined duration.

Comment: I'd liked it to keep recording until the audio source ends. Ideally I guess it should keep randomly using input files from `$playlist` on repeat